# Loading Select2 with a selected option WITHOUT triggering change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Is there any way to load select2 to a default value without triggering the change event?

Currently, I am doing:

```
$('#mylist').val(2).trigger("change");
```

But this creates a delay where the user will at first see one option and then it will change, which is quite an annoyance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a default value in your HTML:

```
<select id="myList">
   <option id="foo">option 1</option>
   <option id="bar" selected="selected">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Then call `select2` on your element to initialize it:

`$('#myList').select2();`

or

`$('#myList').select2("val", null);`

Answer (score 38):

I know I'm really late to answer this question. I was facing the same issue. But doing a bit of research I found a solution that works like a charm.

You can set an option using below code

`$("#mylist").val(2).trigger('change.select2');`

This solution will not trigger the main change event but sets the option to the `select2` component.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: It does trigger change event

Comment: @Aditya This triggers a change event within select2, but it will not trigger an event that was set using .on("change"). Thus, select2 will process the change, but a custom change event will not.

Comment: Exactly, the change event will be very specific to the select2 and not the main change event.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to set a selected option, normaly you can do:

```
 $('#element').val('your_val').trigger('change');
```

But if you dont want to run the trigger, you  must to destroy it first and then assign val before create again, like this:

```
$('#element').select2('destroy');
$('#element').val('your_val').select2();
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the best method is using the [scope](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event) of select2:

```
$('#mylist').val('value');
$('#mylist').trigger('change.select2');
```